# German-Danish / Danish-German dictionary for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, dictionary

I need a German-Danish and/or Danish-German dictionary. I have tried searching Google, but there's really not many dictionaries out there for Mac OS X it seems.

Do you know of any? 
I don't care if it's freeware or not. I'm willing to buy a professional dictionary if I have to.

Answer (score 1):

[stardict](http://stardict.sourceforge.net) seems to work on Mac OS X.

You might want to investigate the links at its site and see if there are dictionaries for those languages that you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you are OK with running [Wine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_%28software%29) then the commercial [Gyldendals Ordbog Dansk-Tysk / Tysk-Dansk](http://www.transmedia.dk/shop/gyldendals-ordbog-dansk-tysk-632p.html) (DKK 845)
can be used:

[Installation af Gyldendals Røde Ordbøger](http://www.linuxin.dk/node/271).